# how to make this code on python run faster?

Tags: python, performance, helper

I wrote this snippet on python to resolve project Euler problem #10, but i've been waiting 15 minutes (running this code) and it still doesn't end.

Please help me to improve this code or optimize it.

Here is the snippet:

```
def prime (n):
  f = 1 #flag
  for i in range(2,n):
    if n % i == 0:
        f = 0
  return f

s = 0 # Sum
for i in range(2,2000000):
if prime(i) == 1:
    s = i  +  s
print s
```

Comment: Did you try [searching for previous answers about Python and primes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+prime)?

Comment: Well - a simplest thing is - you don't have to run all the way up to n in finding out a prime, sqrt(n) would make it run considerably faster.

Comment: @gabhijit immediate return would make it much faster :)

Comment: Oh yes!! @alik - sorry missed that! :)

Comment: Another simple thing would be to return the value directly instead of continuing to loop over everything else, or even just `return all(n%i != 0 for i in range(2,n))`.

Comment: @gabhijit - I think that Alik's comment was a joke. If you just immediately return, it'd be _faster_, but give the wrong answer.

Comment: Also, like tepples said, why don't you just [try searching for what other people did](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+euler+10+python)?

Comment: @DaoWen, I meant immediate return once you've found out, that a number is divisible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import math

def prime (n):
    for i in xrange(2, int(math.sqrt(n))+1):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

s = 2 # Sum
for i in xrange(3,2000000, 2):
    if prime(i):
        s += i
print s
```

It runs in less than 10 seconds for me.

First of all, you want to return from `prime` once you found out, that a numer is composite.

Second, you do not want to check even numbers. Skip them with `xrange(3,2000000, 2)`

Third, there is no need to check all numbers from `2` to `n` in `prime`, because `a*b = b*a`

Since you use Python 2 I've replaced `range` with `xrange`, it will be a little bit more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all prime numbers till 2000000, you should consider using **Sieve of Eratosthenes**.

Code in python : -

```
def eratosthenes2(n):
    multiples = set()
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        if i not in multiples:
            yield i
            multiples.update(range(i*i, n+1, i))

print(list(eratosthenes2(2000000)))
```

Source - http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Python

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes